# Disable activex alert popup

Tags: plugins

[image: This security alert popup is getting triggered everytime when we r about to use ActiveX in our page. This is not allowing the page to displayed in browser. But I want this to be disabled. This alert popup should not be triggered. It should allow the page without asking this popup. what should we suppose to change in browser settings for it to get disabled. Please help me out in it. Thanks in advance]

This security alert popup is getting triggered every time when we use ActiveX in our page, preventing it from displaying in the browser.

I want to disable this alert popup. It should allow the page to load without this prompt. How can I change my settings to stop this alert?

Comment: @Matti ... wait a few minutes for him!

Comment: Ok, now it's a question. @belisarius: Most people don't post their question before actually adding the... question.

Comment: @Matti The question was there ... but inside the image description brackets. I was tempted to edit it, but I gave the OP a few seconds and he did it himself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tools -> Options -> Advanced [Tab]
```

Scroll Down to

```
Security
```

And check

```
Allow active content to run files n my Computer.
```

Are you going to do this in all of your user's PC? Hope it is an intranet application and you have control over the user's PC. If it is an internet website. Forget it! :)